# Can DCO be used in BSL?

Tags: gpl, license-compatibility, developer-certificate-of-origin

A [Developer Certificate of Origin](https://developercertificate.org/) is a well adopted contribution model in open source projects that protects both the contributors rights of their changes and the project. Could it also be used in projects that have [Business Source License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Source_License) given that the contribution will, eventually of course, be transformed into a GPL license?

Answer (score 5):

I would strongly recommend against using the DCO for anything involving the BSL - the DCO makes references to "open source licence(s)" and the BSL is *not* an open source license, even if code licensed under the BSL converts to open source down the line.